# Problem in updating a data column in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Database table called ProgramData. their i have a data column called Id and executed. id set to be as auto increment.

Table structure is like this.

[image]

What i want is according to id executed column need to be updated. following is my code segment.

```
 public void saveDtvProgDataExecuted()
  {
    ProgramData programeData = new ProgramData();
    String SQL = "UPDATE program_data SET executed=1 WHERE programeData.id = ?";
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(SQL);
}
```

If i run this code this gives me error like **bad SQL grammar [UPDATE program_data SET executed=1 WHERE programeData.id = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1**

Comment: are you passing the value of    { programeData.id = ?}

Comment: I think your error is that you mistyped your table name there in the WHERE clause...  You could just write `WHERE id = ?`. But @this_is_om_vm is right - when you get past that, it will complain because you did not pass in a value for the ? placeholder.

Comment: No actually i don`t know how to pass it.

Comment: @moilejter problem is i cant think how to pass that id and where should i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you’re not passing the ID value to the jdbctemplate.

You should use 
    this.jdbctemplate.update(SQL, id); 
Where id is the id of the record you’re updating.

Please refer to the documentation for more information:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#jdbc-updates

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS statement while you are passing ? in your sql query it need to be set while execution.

```
 String SQL = "UPDATE program_data SET executed=1 WHERE programeData.id = ?";
   this.jdbcTemplate.update(SQL,new PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean>(){  
    @Override  
    public Boolean doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps)  
            throws SQLException, DataAccessException {  

        ps.setInt(1,"here you need to pass value of programeData.id);  
        return ps.execute();  
              }  
    });
```